# How is Google Drive streaming my h264 in browser?

Tags: google-drive, video-streaming

Just as the question asks I'm simply currious how they play video without a container. Perhaps they do it on the fly container ? Or they reconvert my video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely answer is that Google re-encodes your video when it is uploaded to Google Drive.

Google Drive's video player seems to be nearly identical to YouTube's video player. It's  a fairly safe assumption that Google uses similar video encoding methods for both products.